Using FlutterGeofencing sample plugin Flutter
I have been trying to use this sample plugin for geofencing: FlutterGeofencing
When I call the method registerGeofence I get the following error:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient, but class was expected.

My Code is as follows:
void registerGeofence() async {
    final firstPermission = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
    final secondPermission = await Permission.locationAlways.request();
    if (firstPermission.isGranted && secondPermission.isGranted) {
      await GeofencingManager.registerGeofence(
        GeofenceRegion(
          'mtv',
          latitude,
          longitude,
          1000,
          _triggers,
          androidSettings: _androidSettings,
        ),
        callback,
      );
      final registeredIds = await GeofencingManager.getRegisteredGeofenceIds();
      debugPrint("registerGeofence -> registeredIds: $registeredIds");
    } else {
      debugPrint(
          "right permissions not set: whenInUser: 
${Permission.locationWhenInUse.isGranted}, always: 
${Permission.locationAlways.isGranted}");
    }
  }

I have clone the github code and aa it to my project as follows:
dev_dependencies:
      geofencing:
        path: /local_path/FlutterGeofencing

Thanks
